# When using the 'Class' datatype, how can I specify the type so I only accept subclass of a specific class?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, actionscript, superclass

I've got a method that accepts a parameter of type `Class`, and I want to only accept classes that extend `SuperClass`. Right now, all I can figure out to do is this, which does a run-time check on an instance:

```
public function careless(SomeClass:Class):void {
    var instance:SomeClass = new SomeClass();
    if (instance as SuperClass) {
        // great, i guess
    } else {
        // damn, wish i'd have known this at compile time
    }

}
```

Is there any way to do something like this, so I can be assured that a `Class` instance extends some super class?

```
public function careful(SomeClass:[Class extends SuperClass]):void {
    var instance:SuperClass = new SomeClass();
    // all is good
}
```

Comment: Not likely - though I don't see why you want to instantiate like this.  why not just do `function careful(instance:SuperClass)`  then do  `careful(new MySubClass())`, then it will compile time error on you if not a sub class.

Comment: Do you need to use the instance you create for something, or are you only creating it to check if it is a subclass? Could you not just pass in a newly-created object that you know is a subclass and use that?

Comment: @mfa There are likely better ways to build the application I'm working on, but with the way it's all set up, I need to pass in a Class so that it can be instantiated many times by other objects later. The specific code up there was just to show a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to instantiate it anyway, why not accept an object instead which allows you to type it to `:SuperClass`?

```
careless(SomeClass);
//vs.
careless(new SomeClass);
```

Not too much of a problem there as far as your code goes.
There are a few differences though:

- The object has to be created, because an object is required. If your function does not instantiate the class under some circumstances, this can be a problem. Additional logic to pass either an object or null can bloat the function call.
- If you cannot call the constructor outside that function, it won't
  work either.

All that is solved by the factory pattern. Pass a factory as the parameter that produces `SuperClass` objects.

```
function careful(factory:SuperClassFactory)
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the factory pattern – going to look into that, as it might indeed be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Factory pattern turned out to be exactly what I needed for this application. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements:

> I want to only accept classes that extend SuperClass

and

> I need to pass in a Class so that it can be instantiated many times
>   by other objects later

Can be met by passing in an instance of the class you need, and using the Object.constructor() method.

```
public function careful(someInstance:SuperClass):void {
    //you probably want to store classRef in a member variable
    var classRef: Class = someInstance.constructor();

    //the following is guaranteed to cast correctly,
    //since someInstance will always be a descendant of SuperClass  
    var myInst:SuperClass = new classRef() as SuperClass; 
}
```

[More reading here.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#constructor)

Comment: That's a neat solution. Maybe the only problem is that it requires a throwaway instance to be created? I ended up using the factory pattern to solve my particular problem, which I think will get me out of needing to use this. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in ActionScript 3. In languages like C# you can do something like (forgive me if the syntax is off):

```
public void Careless<T>() where T : SuperClass
```

But AS3 does not have 'generics'. Unfortunately the only way I know how to do what you want is the way you have already done.

A pattern that might be more suitable for your use case might be something like:

```
class SuperClass
{
    public static function careless():void
    {
       var instance:SuperClass = new SuperClass();

       // ...
    }
}
```

The only way to have static type checking in ActionScript 3 is to provide an *instance* of a class.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but it's expensive. You can use on a Class (not instance) the:

```
flash.utils.describeType
```

You then get an XML with a bunch of information including inheritance for that class. Like I said it's an expensive process and probably creating an instance and checking it will be in most cases faster.

Comment: That's at runtime though.

Comment: The question is runtime based and so are all answers, what's your point?

Comment: The question is asking how to avoid runtime checking, and the answers are attempting to provide static type checking.

Comment: Your own answer is runtime based. The PO examples are runtime based. Creating an instance of a class pertain to runtime based check not compile time. My answer is the closest to compile time check that you can get since it's the only one that works without the need to create an instance of a class.

Comment: Creating an instance is runtime based but if in your code you could potentially create an instance of the wrong class, the compiler will pick it up, whereas your example needs to check the XML at runtime... Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I'm not trying to argue or anything but if I understand correctly what you are saying is: create a static function, create an instance of class inside it, check its type: this is compile time. On the other hand, create a static function, use describeType on a passed class, check the type, this is runtime. Sorry that doesn't make any sense, no.

Comment: None of the answers do said checking though, they suggest using a class instance so the compiler can do the check, or using similar to the factory pattern as a workaround.