# Check if class extends another class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

To be clear, I want to check a class, not an instance of that class.

```
public function changeScene(newScene:Class):void 
{
  if(newScene isExtending Scene)
  //...
}
```

It's a variable of type Class.

Edit: More details.
What the function does (simplified):

```
public function changeScene(newScene:Class):void 
{
    currentScene.finish(); //Finish the scene that is about to change

    //Check if the new scene don't exist prior this point
    if (!scenes[newScene])  //Look in dictionary
        addScene(newScene); //Create if first time accessing it

    scenes[newScene].caller = currentScene["constructor"];
    currentScene = scenes[newScene];
    currentScene.start();
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28205385/when-using-the-class-datatype-how-can-i-specify-the-type-so-i-only-accept-sub/28220451#28220451) doesn't work for me because I don't create new instances all the time, I reused them most of the time. The instances are stored in a dictionary using the class as the key.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28205385/when-using-the-class-datatype-how-can-i-specify-the-type-so-i-only-accept-sub/28220451#28220451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the only way I can think of to do this without instantiating objects:

You use `flash.utils.getQualifiedSuperclassName` the get the super class of a class.  Since that returns a string, you have to then use `flash.utils.getDefinitionByName` to get the actual class reference.

So you could write a function that walks up the inheritance until it either finds a match, or reaches `Object` (the base of everything).

```
import flash.utils.getQualifiedSuperclassName;
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

function extendsClass(cls:Class, base:Class):Boolean {
    while(cls != null && cls != Object){
        if(cls == base) return true;
        cls = getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedSuperclassName(cls)) as Class; //move on the next super class
    }
    return false;
}

trace(extendsClass(MovieClip,Sprite)); //true
trace(extendsClass(MovieClip,Stage)); //false
```

Comment: To be clear though, instantiating first and checking the instance would be better and give you compile time checking.   If you showed what you do after `if(newScene isExtending Scene)` a more tailored solution could be given - as while this answers your question, it's not necessarily the best way to make your application.

Answer (score 0):

> The other question doesn't work for me because I don't create new
>   instances all the time, I reused them most of the time. The instances
>   are stored in a dictionary using the class as the key.

I beg to differ.

The factory pattern encapsulates the entire creation of the object of a certain class. That also includes limiting how often the class is instantiated.
If you only want the factory to ever produce one object, that's possible. It will turn into a `Singleton`.

Comment: PO is just using a complicated and weak way to replicate a very simple and easy to use Singleton pattern.